# PHP not echo-ing

Tags: php, echo

I've run into this problem with a custom Log In script; The redirects work fine, but it's not echoing the alert here is my code:

```
        if ($_POST['submit']) {

            sleep(6);

            $expire = time() + (24 * 60 * 60);
            $cookie = 'level of clearence';

            if ($passcode == ($level4||$level3||$level2||$level1)) {
                echo '<script>alert("Happy Hacking");</script>';
                //    setcookie($cookie, 'level4', $expire);

                header('Location: home.php');
            }
            else if ($passcode != ($level4||$level3||$level2||$level1)) {
                echo '<script>alert("Incorrect PassCode");</script>';
                header('Location: index.php');
            }

        }
```

Comment: And also, Print Doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Can't use PHP redirection here. Use JavaScript redirection instead.

Comment: Is this an Ajax script? If so, use a JavaScript redirection. If not, the alert script won't show up because you're redirecting to an entirely different page.

Comment: It's not echoing anything because that's not how redirect responses work.  If the `Location` header tells the browser to redirect, the browser ignores any content and just issues the new directed request.

Comment: Javascript redirects aren't working, they refresh the page instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot issue Headers after the output is already sent.

```
            echo '<script>alert("Incorrect PassCode");</script>';
            header('Location: index.php'); // This wont work after your echo
```

That code Won't work. You can change that to a JavaScript redirect

```
           echo '<script>
                   alert("Incorrect PassCode");
                   location.href="index.php";
                 </script>';
```

According to [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.